# Convert getIntersect(arr1, arr2) Javascript function to any number of arguments and in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, function

This is a two part question.  The first part is converting the function below to accept any number of arrays.

```
function getIntersect(arr1, arr2) {
    var r = [], o = {}, l = arr2.length, i, v;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        o[arr2[i]] = true;
    }
    l = arr1.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        v = arr1[i];
        if (v in o) {
            r.push(v);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

This function snippet is thanks to Ian and Jeffrey from this post.
http://www.falsepositives.com/index.php/2009/12/01/javascript-function-to-get-the-intersect-of-2-arrays/

I am interested because the performance of using the hash table is so much better than the index method of the Underscore Utility belt and the jquery-rich-array plugin.  I am aware that Jquery has a method, jQuery.inArray(), however the docs make it sound like it too uses index, and I am looking for the optimal performance solution to sort through arrays with over ten thousand elements.

The second part of my question is making it Jquery friendly.  Presuming the JSON object below, using Jquery how to 1) select only the arrays1-5, load them into the function and return one array.

```
{
    "Container1": {
        "Array1":      ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"], 
        "Array2":      ["Sunday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"], 
        "Array3":      ["Sunday", "Friday", "Saturday"], 
        "Array4":      ["Sunday",  "Friday", "Garbage"], 
        "Array5":      ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        "ArrayOthers1":      ["1", "6", "8", "5"],
        "ArrayOthers2":      ["1", "6", "8", "5"],
        "ArrayOthers3":      ["1", "6", "8", "5"]
    }
}
```

The answer to the above is an array = ["Sunday","Friday"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start by using your `getIntersect()` function as a helper to a newly created `getIntersectN()` function:

```
function getIntersect(arr1, arr2) {
    var r = [], o = {}, l = arr2.length, i, v;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        o[arr2[i]] = true;
    }
    l = arr1.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        v = arr1[i];
        if (v in o) {
            r.push(v);
        }
    }
    return r;
}

function getIntersectN(){
    // call signature: getIntersectN(arr1, arr2, ..., arrN)
    // NOTE: alternatively you can explicitly pass in an 'args' array to change the call signature to:
    //     getIntersectN(args) [then just replace 'arguments' below with 'args']
    if(arguments.length == 0) return [];
    else if(arguments.length == 1) return arguments[0];

    var intersect = arguments[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        intersect = getIntersect(intersect, arguments[i]);
    }
    return intersect;
}

var data = {
    "Array1":      ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"], 
    "Array2":      ["Sunday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"], 
    "Array3":      ["Sunday", "Friday", "Saturday"], 
    "Array4":      ["Sunday",  "Friday", "Garbage"], 
    "Array5":      ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    "ArrayOthers1":      ["1", "6", "8", "5"],
    "ArrayOthers2":      ["1", "6", "8", "5"],
    "ArrayOthers3":      ["1", "6", "8", "5"]
};

console.log(getIntersectN(data.Array1, data.Array2, data.Array3, data.Array4, data.Array5));
```

As for the jQuery, if you are loading the JSON from an AJAX callback, then:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        var container = response.Container1;
        var intersection = getIntersectN(container.Array1, ... container.Array5);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a great answer!  Could you elaborate on the Jquery part? Is it possible to create a string and feed it?  For example: "getIntersectN("container." + "MyArrayName,container." + "MySecondArrayName");

Comment: @Ariesto I'm not sure what you mean by `create a string and feed it`. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this part?

Comment: I am in a situation where I will create this list of arrays by iterating over other information, creating 1 string. Pretend you have a var MyArrayChoices  = "container.test[Array1],container.test[Array54]". Then I can use my string variable and eval() to run your function like so:  getIntersectN(eval(MyArrayChoices)) which almost works, but eval is only working on the last array54 and ignoring returning results for the Array1, or maybe it is because I submit all of it as a string to your function.   Does that clear up what I'm trying to do? These comments are very hard to format :(

Comment: A second stab at what I am looking for:
getIntersectN(eval("container.Array1,container.Array5")); 

Or as arrays:

getIntersectN(eval('[Sunday,Monday,Tuesday],[Sunday,Friday]'))

It returns the wrong answer: [Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Friday] instead of [Sunday,Friday].

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `eval()`. How are you getting the array keys that you need to join? Why not just use the keys to build a `subset` array and then pass that to `getIntersectN()`? i.e. as you get the strings, push `container[stringKey]` onto `subset[]` with `subset.push(container[stringKey])`, then `getIntersectN(subset)`. _NOTE: You would need to change its call signature to take a single array in that case._

Comment: dgilland you are a lifesaver.  Following your advice I changed `getIntersectN()` to accept one array. I missed that your original answer contained documentation on how to change the call signature. In addition, I needed to call the JSON object field via the [] that way I can use a loop like this: `$.each(ArrayKeys, function (intIndex, objValue) {subset.push(container[objValue]);};`  Everything works per my requirements!  Thanks again :)